# Dynamoose and DynamoDB Secondary Index searching

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

i'm trying to search a table based on 2 attributes. However i'm getting the following error:

> ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element

What i'm doing:

```js
let value = 'dsadsada';
Cache.query({'registration': { 'eq': value}, 'derivativeId': { 'eq': null}}).exec();
```

Expected result:
Return a list of documents where the registration matches the value but the derivativeId is null.

I'm using `dynamoose`, so first of all this is the model:

```js
import {model} from "dynamoose";
import {Document} from 'dynamoose/dist/Document';
import {Schema} from 'dynamoose/dist/Schema';

class Cache extends Document {
    id: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
}

const schema = {
    types: {
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        registration: {
            type: String,
            index: {
                name: 'VehicleLookupIndex',
                global: true
            }
        },
        derivativeId: {
            type: String,
            index: {
                name: 'VehicleLookupIndex'
            }
        }
    },
    options: {
        timestamps: true,
        saveUnknown: ['**'],
        expires: 10
    },
};

model.defaults.set({
    create: false,
    prefix: process.env.TABLE_PREFIX
});

export default model<Cache>('cache', new Schema(schema.types, schema.options));
```

This is my `serverless` file where I define the table:

```yaml
cache:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: ${self:provider.stage}-${self:service}-cache
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: 'VehicleLookupIndex'
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: 'id'
            KeyType: 'HASH'
        Projection:
          NonKeyAttributes:
            - 'derivativeId'
            - 'registration'
          ProjectionType: 'INCLUDE'
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: This looks more like a bug than a question. Please submit an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: @CharlieFish Ah okay will do, thought I may have just have been me being an idiot and done it wrong lol

Comment: @CharlieFish I don't think this is a bug tbh.